# How to create (d . nil) in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am beginner in Lisp. There is a question that I cannot solve.

Show the simplest expression that Lisp will print out when you type the following
expression:

```
’(a b (c . e) (d . nil))
```

I tried `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons (cons 'c 'e) (cons (cons 'd nil)))))`

However, it wouldn't create (d . nil).

So, is there any way to create such a dot pair?

Comment: *Show the simplest expression that Lisp will print out when you type the following expression: `’(a b (c . e) (d . nil))`* If you copied the "question" exactly as written, then this is asking for you to show what Lisp prints out when you type, `’(a b (c . e) (d . nil))`. It's not asking what to type to get that expression. In that case, the answer is simply, `(a b (c . e) (d))`

Comment: @luker thank you! I realized I did wrong thing.

Comment: The question is misleading. A given Lisp implementation will print the object in exactly one way, not in multiple ways where we can find one that is simpler than the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Show the simplest expression that Lisp will print out when you type the following expression

The question does not ask you to create a dotted pair, but how the dotted pair is printed. I suppose this question aims at showing you that lists are just dotted pairs printed in a special way.

If you write this in a REPL:

```
'(a b (c . e) (d . nil))
```

The REPL replies:

```
(A B (C . E) (D))
```

You have the exact same output if you write:

```
'(a . (b . ((c . e) . ((d . nil) . nil))))
```

Basically, `(a b)` is the list made of a symbol `a` in front of a sublist `(b)`, written `(a . (b))`. Here I am only talking about how forms are *read*. If you write them directly in the REPL, they will first be *read*, then *evaluated*, and in that case you will get an error. That's why in the examples are quoted: an expression being quoted is not evaluated, but returned as-is.

If you want to write code that, when evaluated, produces the cons-cell `(0 . 1)`, you have to write this list:

```
(cons 0 1)
```

The above is a list of three elements, which could be written equally:

```
(cons . (0 . (1 . nil)))
```

Your interpreter will read this list (a symbol, two numbers) and evaluate the resulting form. That forms produces, at runtime, the following cons cell:

```
(0 . 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just realize I did wring thing.